# Can't get lightbox jquery to work

Tags: jquery, html, lightbox2

I am trying to use lightbox 2 and I can't seem to get it to work. I am currently testing it on one image and nothing is happening. Any help would be appreciated!

```
    <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gallery.css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   </head>
    <body>
  <a href="images/bethan6.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1"><img src="images/bethan6.jpg" /></a>

     <script src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
     </body>
```

Comment: It looks okay to me. are the path to css and js file correct?

Comment: yeah. I made a js and css folder and I have all the images in my image folder. I have tried looking up tutorials to see what I am doing wrong and every tutorial I have come across are out dated and not very clear. I have spent hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: okay as @user3207826 has answered, you need to add http:// while loading jquery in your code

Comment: I am not sure if I did it correctly now. Sorry, I have never used jquery or javascript before. I added it to my question.

Comment: did you check your browsers console (press F12 and check the console tab)?

Comment: Try this, put the script of bootstrap.min.js before the closing of body tag. It should work.

Comment: Glad it worked. I guess you understood the problem too. Bootstrap loaded faster than jquery and it didn't understand the $ variable.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have invoked jQuery incorrectly, which would prevent Lightbox from working.

Try this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Your current code would look through your own file system for code.jquery.com, which I hope you haven't taken the trouble to download.

EDIT: Judging from the [Lightbox Documentation](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) it doesn't seem that you need to include the `<img>` tag in the `<a>` tag. The image will display by itself.

Comment: hmmm it still doesn't seem to work. I added the change to my question.

Comment: I have tried. If I don't include the image tag it will just show up as a link that people click to get the image. The thumbnail won't show up. But even when I do that the just goes to another page. It doesn't pop out like it should.